# What is the first movie to introduce changing future by travelling into future?

Tags: first-appearance

In [13 Going On 30](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0337563/), Jenna Rink (**30 year old**) missed Matt as husband in first time travel.

Then she came back to past (**13 year old**), then she understand her mistake.
Finally she marries him in present (**30 year old**).

She has changed her future by travelling into future. What is the first movie to do it?

Comment: *Did* she travel into the future?  It sounds like she returned to the present, having traveled into the past.  I haven't seen the movie, so maybe there's something I'm missing?

Comment: @Steve-O yes, she did go from 13 to 30. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0337563/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl

Comment: Yeah, but according to what the OP said in the question, she *started* at 30, went back in time to 13, then returned to her original timeframe.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding what the OP means by "changed her future by travelling into [the] future."  The only two time frames I see are her past and her present, not her future.

Answer (score -1):

The first **story** to do it was probably [HG Wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._G._Wells)', [The Time Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Machine); anything else followed that plot.... but I've no clue which movie did it first.

Whether the 1949 [TV show](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0294968/?ref_=nv_sr_6) was the first, I really don't know.

..over to the research team...